# Design pattern: singleton with setting capabilities

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Sorry for the title, I will try to better explain the problem.
I have create a wrapper for my log4net instance, I instantiate this logger with the following constructor:

```
    public MyLogger(string _dbName)
    {
        dbName = _dbName;
        logger = LoggerConfigurator.AddNamedLogger(dbName);
    }
```

Now the problem is: this constructor is instantiated in two different classes, so some message-logs are printed twice.
I need to create a new instance only if previous instance doesn't exist, otherwise return the instance. A sort of Singleton pattern. The problem is that Singleton pattern doesn't accept parameters, so I haven't a way to pass `_dbName`. How can I handle this following a best practice?

Comment: why not to use Singleton x = Singleton.GetInstance(params object[] parameters); or create Init method which initialize singleton with parameters set? x.Init(params object[] parameters);

Comment: Or even better - use a IoC Container! There you can define, that only one instance of your Type `<T>` should be used for all classes that are having dependencies to it. Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a Multiton ([Multiton pattern on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)). It is basically a singleton per key (this is the C# example on Wikipedia):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace MyApplication 
{
    class FooMultiton 
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, FooMultiton> _instances
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, FooMultiton>();

        private FooMultiton() {}

        public static FooMultiton GetInstance(object key) 
        {
            _instances.TryAdd(key, new FooMultiton()); // This would of course be new MyLogger(_dbName)
            return _instances[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: The sample is wrong, an instance of FooMultiton will be created each time you call GetInstance ! I fixed it on wikipedia using GetOrAdd instead of TryAdd.

Comment: @Guillaume it is of course more the idea than the actual implementation and depending on what happens in the constructor it could be changed into ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<FooMultiton>>

Comment: It is not so useful (for me) to have a list of singleton.
I need just a singleton at time, with parameters relative to a given operation on DB

Comment: I've choice yours as accepted answer, cause in this way (even if I store all the loggers without any real benefit) in a single row `log = MyLogger.GetInstance(builder.InitialCatalog);` I can get what I need. In the other solutions: I first have to set the static `name` property and after this step I can finally get the Instance (I consider this issue really error prone and bad styled.) So...

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not advised to give the singleton's "getHandle" method a parameter, I'd say you need to pass the `dbName` as a separate static property, e.g.

```
class MyLogger {

private String dbname = String.Empty;

public static String DbName {
    get { return dbname; }
    set { dbname = value; }
}

private static MyLogger mylogger = null;

public static MyLogger Handle {
    get {
        if (logger == null) mylogger = new MyLogger(dbName);
        return mylogger;
    }
}

private MyLogger(String db) {
    // your code
    logger = LoggerConfigurator.AddNamedLogger(db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton _instance;

    private MySingleton()
    {
    }
    private MySingleton(params object[] parameters)
    {
        // assign parameters
    }
    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("not created");
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public static void Create(params object[] parameters)
    {
        if (_instance != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _instance = new MySingleton(parameters);
    }
}
```

Needs some synchronization for multiply threads.